# In-house FAQ/knowledge base that can work offline

Tags: windows, offline, knowledge-base

We are trying to organise an employee FAQ that will have lots of questions and issues that we run into with our products and their solutions. There are tons of these out there but we specifically are looking for one we can use offline when on-site with a customer as during install is when most problems can happen. So we can have the entire directory of searchable potential issues on our laptops to quickly find the solution.

- We have about 1000 posts of various problems we ran into when installing or questions from customers (they have tags) and each one has a few replies with the answer or how the error was fixed. So it just needs to be very searchable.
- It will need to sync so when we don't have internet when at the client we can still use it (pharma companies don't allow WiFi or phones in the labs).

We use Confluence and Jira so I did look into the Answers addon but it does not look like offline is an option. Discourse also looked like a good option but again not sure if the offline will work how we want it.

Has anyone else used any solutions for internal FAQs that are good? Or know of any that are available offline specifically?

OS is Windows.

Budget I am not sure yet (it doesn't need to be free or anything) but I am sure that any solution can't be more than I will be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

How about a hosted Wiki, served from a master server in office network? (that is only accessible inside office)

You can search by feature here: http://www.wikimatrix.org/search.php

Comment: Can you recommend one which works offline?

Comment: @Mawg I can't since I haven't tried any of them. Assuming you want a hosted solution like the original poster, any hosted software that is served from a master server should be okay, which should work offline as long as you're connected to the intranet (not internet).

Comment: Nvm, I really ought to have posted my own question ;-) @Ben, have you found an answer?

Comment: Btw, I wasn't aware of WikiMatrix, so many thanks for that. Similar, for CMS is http://www.cmsmatrix.org/ which is slightly more wizard driven.